# Julia: How to make colwise return an array instead of an array of arrays?

Tags: julia

I wanted to make a function that looks at every column of a DataFrame and return a boolean, so I end up with an array of booleans. Here is the code

```
# some random dataframe
df = DataFrame([1:3, 4:6])

# a function that returns an array of boolean
function some_bool_fn(df)::Array{Bool}
    array_of_arrays = colwise(df) do sdd3
        # for illustration only
        return true
    end
    array = [a[1] for a in array_of_arrays]
    return array
end

# calling the function
some_bool_fn(dd3)
```

This works except I find the line

```
        array = [a[1] for a in array_of_arrays]
```

a bit wasteful. Basically I get an array of arrays as the output of `colwise`, so I then had to put the array of arrays into a simple array of bools. Is there a way to write the code so I can avoid this line of code?

Comment: X-ref: https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/commit/5f611bf480632507e15bb2c96bf39aedb71d6d06

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Gnimuc commented this behaviour is changing.

If you look at master branch: https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/src/groupeddataframe/grouping.jl#L241 you'll see another version. You could probably copy it:

```
mycolwise(f, d::AbstractDataFrame) = [f(d[i]) for i in 1:ncol(d)]
```

Comment: How do i make use of this version? Is it Pkg.checkout("DataFrames")

Comment: @xiaodai I think it's an overkill to checkout DataFrames' master for such a small feature(just one line code change) since you're prone to suffering from other breakages. Like Liso suggested in the answer, you cloud define another `colwise` or overwrite `DataFrames.colwise` directly.

Comment: @Gnimuc it is not enough to overwrite only this oneliner because there are more methods defined. Maybe it could be fine to do conditional compiling according to DataFrames version. (BTW how to get this version info?)

Comment: @Liso makes sense. you could get the version number via `Pkg.installed("DataFrames")` ;)